# Directx 9 screen capture c#

Tags: c#, directx, screenshots

Пытаюсь получить изображение через хукование от *DirectX 9*.
Для хука использую функцию `EndScene`.
Далее при помощи `SharpDX` пытаюсь выполнить примерно такой код:

```
var format = Format.A8R8G8B8;

using (var pSurface = Surface.CreateOffscreenPlain(device, width, height,
                            format, Pool.Scratch))
{
   device.GetFrontBufferData(0, pSurface);
   SharpDX.Rectangle rect = new SharpDX.Rectangle(0, 0, width,
                            height);
   SharpDX.DataRectangle lockedRect = pSurface.LockRectangle(rect,
           LockFlags.ReadOnly | LockFlags.NoSystemLock | LockFlags.NoDirtyUpdate);
   ProcessCapture(rect.Width, rect.Height, lockedRect.Pitch, lockedRect.DataPointer, pSurface.Description.Format.ToPixelFormat());
   pSurface.UnlockRectangle();
}
```

В результате `GetFrontBufferData` падает с ошибкой:

```
HRESULT: [0x8876086C], Module: [SharpDX.Direct3D9], ApiCode: [D3DERR_INVALIDCALL/InvalidCall], Message: Unknown
```

*Часть 2:*
Есть более сложный код, который работает, но там происходит проблема - скрин экрана иногда переворачивается. Как это исправить не знаю. в DirectX не силен.

Подскажите, что делаю не так.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заработало решение из части 2. проблема с переворачивание изображений решилась проверкой параметров в `device.VertexFormat`

код из части 2

```
using (Surface renderTarget = device.GetRenderTarget(0))
{
  var width = renderTarget.Description.Width;
  var height = renderTarget.Description.Height;
  var format = renderTarget.Description.Format;

  // If existing _renderTargetCopy, ensure that it is the correct size and format
  if (_renderTargetCopy != null && (_renderTargetCopy.Description.Width != width || _renderTargetCopy.Description.Height != height || _renderTargetCopy.Description.Format != format))
  {
    // Cleanup resources
    Cleanup();
  }

  // Ensure that we have something to put the render target data into
  if (!_resourcesInitialised || _renderTargetCopy == null)
  {
    CreateResources(device, width, height, format);
  }

  // Resize from render target Surface to resolvedSurface (also deals with resolving multi-sampling)
  device.StretchRectangle(renderTarget, _resolvedTarget, TextureFilter.None);
}

// Copy data from resolved target to our render target copy
device.GetRenderTargetData(_resolvedTarget, _renderTargetCopy);

// Lock the render target
SharpDX.Rectangle rect;
SharpDX.DataRectangle lockedRect = LockRenderTarget(_renderTargetCopy, out rect);
_renderTargetCopyLocked = true;

lock (_lockRenderTarget)
{
  ProcessCapture(rect.Width, rect.Height, lockedRect.Pitch, lockedRect.DataPointer, _renderTargetCopy.Description.Format.ToPixelFormat());
}

// If the render target is locked from a previous request unlock it
if (_renderTargetCopyLocked)
{
  // Wait for the the ProcessCapture thread to finish with it
  lock (_lockRenderTarget)
  {
    if (_renderTargetCopyLocked)
    {
      _renderTargetCopy.UnlockRectangle();
      _renderTargetCopyLocked = false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ага, вот так гораздо лучше )